# How to label a line in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I followed the documentation but still failed to label a line.

```
plt.plot([min(np.array(positions)[:,0]), max(np.array(positions)[:,0])], [0,0], color='k', label='East') # West-East
plt.plot([0,0], [min(np.array(positions)[:,1]), max(np.array(positions)[:,1])], color='k', label='North') # South-North
```

In the code snippet above, I am trying to plot out the North direction and the East direction.

`position` contains the points to be plotted.

**But I end up with 2 straight lines with NO labels** as follows:
[image]

Where went wrong?

Comment: As far as I know the label argument is for the legend. You may want to look at this for annotation: http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html - put in a plt.legend() and you will see the labels turn up.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The argument `label` is used to set the string that will be shown in the legend. For example consider the following snippet:

```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  plt.plot([1,2,3],'r-',label='Sample Label Red')
  plt.plot([0.5,2,3.5],'b-',label='Sample Label Blue')
  plt.legend()
  plt.show()
```

This will plot 2 lines as shown:
[image: Plot With 2 lines]

The arrow function supports labels. Do check this link:
http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.arrow

Answer (score 4):

when adding the **label** attribute, don't forget to add **.legend()** method.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2],[3,5],'ro',label='one')
plt.plot([1,2],[1,2],'g^',label='two')
plt.plot([1,2],[1,6],'bs',label='three')
plt.axis([0,4,0,10])
plt.ylabel('x2')
plt.xlabel('x1')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
plt.legend(YourDataFrame.columns)
```