# Simple label in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to label different data in a figure and use the standard definition `label='test'`!

```
ax = df.plot(style=['tab:blue'],linewidth=1.0, label ='test')
dfh.plot(ax=ax, style=['tab:orange'], linewidth=1.0, label="line1")
leg =plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

But as you can see this does not work!

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this post answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941083/how-to-label-a-line-in-matplotlib-python

Comment: `ax = df["hahah col"].rename("hahah").plot()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify the legend of pandas bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149428/modify-the-legend-of-pandas-bar-plot)

Answer (score 2):

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1)
axes.plot(df, style=['tab:blue'], linewidth=1.0, label='test')
axes.plot(dfh, style=['tab:orange'], linewidth=1.0, label='line1')
axes.legend()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the matplotlib.pyplot.legend docs (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)

```
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], label='Inline label')
ax.legend()
```

Your code should be:

```
ax.plot(df, style=['tab:blue'],linewidth=1.0, label ='test')
ax.plot(dfh, style=['tab:orange'], linewidth=1.0, label="line1")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```